# jQuery and scroll requiring reload to work

Tags: javascript, wordpress

For some reason the class that's supposed to get added to my website when we start scrolling is not working until I hit "refresh" or do a right click > inspect element.

I'm guessing it has to do with my JavaScript code (bellow) but i'm unsure what's wrong.

My test page is available here: http://192.46.223.146/publications/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    /* window */
    var window_width, window_height, scroll_top;

    /* admin bar */
    var adminbar = $('#wpadminbar');
    var adminbar_height = 0;

    /* header menu */
    var header = $('#g-header');
    var header_top = 0;

    /* scroll status */
    var scroll_status = '';

    /**
     * window load event.
     */
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        /** current scroll */
        scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();

        /** current window width */
        window_width = $(window).width();

        /** current window height */
        window_height = $(window).height();

        /* get admin bar height */
        adminbar_height = adminbar.length > 0 ? adminbar.outerHeight(true) : 0 ;

        /* get top header menu */
        header_top = header.length > 0 ? header.offset().top - adminbar_height : 0 ;

        /* check sticky menu. */
        sticky_menu();
    
    });

    /**
     * resize event.
     */
    $(window).on('resize', function(event, ui) {
        /** current window width */
        window_width = $(event.target).width();

        /** current window height */
        window_height = $(window).height();

        /** current scroll */
        scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();

        /* check sticky menu. */
        sticky_menu();

    });

    /**
     * scroll event.
     */
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        /** current scroll */
        scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();

        /* check sticky menu. */
        sticky_menu();

    });

    /**
     * Sticky menu
     */
    function sticky_menu() {
        if ( $('#g-header-inner').hasClass('no-header-top') && scroll_top > 0 && window_width > 991) {
            header.addClass('header-fixed');

        } else {
            header.removeClass('header-fixed');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have trace the code and found that when your scroll event is executed on landing of the page, `window_width` value is `undefined`, so make sure you get the value to this variable `window_width` in a `sticky_menu()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your scroll event is executed on landing of the page, `window_width` value is `undefined`

Try to use this little modified code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        /* window */
        var window_height;

        /* admin bar */
        var adminbar = $('#wpadminbar');
        var adminbar_height = 0;

        /* header menu */
        var header = $('#site-navigation');
        var header_top = 0;

        /* scroll status */
        var scroll_status = '';

        /**
         * window load event.
         */
        $(window).on('load', function() {
            /** current window height */
            window_height = $(window).height();

            /* get admin bar height */
            adminbar_height = adminbar.length > 0 ? adminbar.outerHeight(true) : 0 ;

            /* get top header menu */
            header_top = header.length > 0 ? header.offset().top - adminbar_height : 0 ;

            /* check sticky menu. */
            sticky_menu();
        
        });

        /**
         * resize event.
         */
        $(window).on('resize', function(event, ui) {
            /** current window height */
            window_height = $(window).height();
            /* check sticky menu. */
            sticky_menu();

        });

        /**
         * scroll event.
         */
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
            /* check sticky menu. */
            sticky_menu();

        });

        /**
         * Sticky menu
         */
        function sticky_menu( window_width ) {
            scroll_top   = $(window).scrollTop();
            window_width = $(window).width();
            console.log(window_width);
            console.log(scroll_top);
            
            if ( $('#site-navigation').hasClass('main-navigation') && scroll_top > 0 && window_width > 991) {
                header.addClass('header-fixed');

            } else {
                header.removeClass('header-fixed');
            }
        }
});
```